# how to show pagination in my chogesn template page that i have created for my all posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created a template for showing my all posts in this page. It is working properly and showing all posts after than i have set 3posts for per page in my query loop but is not working i have used pagination code in my query loop and i have over 10posts exist.

I have attached my code in google drive in this link. please anyone help me for solving this problem:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3UpZ2JueYNNWldCZ3Y2dnA2alk/view?usp=sharing